# High voltage, low current, power supply for night vision gen. 1+ tube - single AA cell or 3V

Tags: power-supply, boost, high-voltage

I would like to build a new power supply for a gen. 1+ night vision intensifier tube, the current supply is robust but big and heavy plus the input is 9 to 24V.
The tube it self requires approximately 16-18kV and 20 microamperes.
I came across a circuit for such a project but unfortunately it is only for 9V battery, 13,5kV output, plus I cant find out what king of transformer is used. Attached the circuit:
[image: 9v power suplly]
Would be nice if someone could help me with a circuit build commonly available parts, thanks.

Comment: Please provide a link to your circuit. And what, exactly, do you mean by "readily available"? You're not likely to find high voltage transformers in most homes.

Comment: Why don't you just buy an off the shelf supply?

Comment: If you look on the circuit picture, components are easy to buy, the only problem is the transformer for which I have no data and therefore I am not able to buy it, I have no possibility to make one my self, that is what I mean under commonly available(e-shop purchasable).

Comment: I would like to buy one directly, can you pls send me link to an e-shop, it would save me a lot of time trying to manufacture one. I was not able to find one so far

Comment: Where did that circuit come from?  The same magazine probably has a parts-list.   Look at the parts list.  What does it say for T1 transformer?  For T2?    Here's a different one (see page 30, Forrest Mimms IR scope for 6032 tube https://worldradiohistory.com/Archive-Radio-Electronics/70s/1974/Radio-Electronics-1974-08.pdf )

Comment: T1 is a tiny audio-transformer with center-tap input, 3000 ohm output (Radio Shack once sold these.)  T2 is a strobe-trigger transformer.  Schematic is from Electronics Now, Oct 1994.   Parts List https://worldradiohistory.com/hd2/IDX-Consumer/Archive-Radio-Electronics-IDX/IDX/90s/1994/EN-1994-10-OCR-Page-0056.pdf